# Compiler errors when declaring global variables

Tags: c, variables, global

I am trying to declare a global variable and for some reason the compiler isn't liking this. It's saying that it has no storage class or specifier when I've given the type already. Just a minute ago these were local to main, but now I just realized that I'm going to need these global, and for some reason it's not letting me. I want these variables to be seen by all my functions, but most of my functions are currently not in main. So I want them to be shared by all functions.

```
char pa, pb, pc, pd, pe, pf, pg, ph, pi, pj, pk, pl, pm, pn, po;
    pa = 'o';
    pb = pc = pd = pe = pf = pg = ph = pi = pj = pk = pl = pm = pn = po = '+';
```

Comment: You have to initialize those variables at the point of declaration or inside some sort of initializer function. You can't just write statements like `pa = 'o';` outside of a function.

Comment: All these global variables aren't going to win any design awards... Use a local array and pass it to your functions.

Comment: The assignment precludes arrays :/

Comment: When do you expect the statements where you assign values to your `char` variables to execute?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I tested this (see my answer post) on Windows 7 using Qt Creator as a "C" project.

Answer (score 1):

you should put your code within a main() function like this.
I was able to compile this on Windows 7.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Declare global variables for this module */
char pa, pb, pc, pd, pe, pf, pg, ph, pi, pj, pk, pl, pm, pn, po;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    /* Assign your global variables */

    pa = 'o';
    pb = pc = pd = pe = pf = pg = ph = pi = pj = pk = pl = pm = pn = po = '+';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare and assign a (single) variable outside of a function.
Turning your declaration to *single* declarations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char  pa = 'o';
char  pb = '+';
char  pc = '+';
/* many others, omitted for brevity */

int main() {
  printf("%c, %c", pa, pb);
}
```

achieves what you want, without splitting declaration and assignment.

Note that this:

```
char  pb = '+';
char  pc = pb;
```

*could*, in a certain sense, work: when the compiler sees `char pc=pb:`, it has all the needed information to declare pc and initialize it to pb. But it does not because it is not smart enough (more probably because the language says that that kind of initializer (pb) *must be a constant*).

Comment: It would also work with all of the declarations on the same line. Readability is the question.

Comment: I mean `char pa = 'o', pb = '+', ... ;`.

Comment: @Quentin Yes. Moreover, in this case I find more comfortable to use duplicate lines and then lot of typing down-bs-d-down-bs-e-down-bs-f-down-bs-g-down-bs-h ... ah ah ah!